# What is the next logical step for language learning after learning BASIC?

Tags: programming-languages

What is the next logical step for language learning after learning BASIC?

Comment: Nothing. You've learned the best language there is!

Comment: Agreed:) But I would like to expand my programming knowledge. What do you suggest

Comment: Haskell, F#/Scala, Ruby/Python, Erlang... whatever. Pick one that looks interesting, you can stand the ideas behind, and will allow you to accomplish small programs-tasks.

Comment: Assembly language. Learn how the computer *really* works, then work your way back up to higher level languages.

Comment: Where can I learn how to write in assembly for PowerMacG5 or AMD windows xp?

Comment: After BASIC? I recommend INTERMEDIATE. ...And then, one day, if you struggle hard enough, if you have the dedication... ADVANCED could be yours. :)

Comment: There are many logical steps, depending on what you want to do and learn.

Comment: I would like to learn a new language that is similar to basic but not too far a leap in concepts because I'm just a beginner. Also, I know Visual Basic so that is out of the question.

Comment: "It is practically impossible to teach good programming to students that have had a prior exposure to BASIC: as potential programmers they are mentally mutilated beyond hope of regeneration. The use of COBOL cripples the mind; its teaching should, therefore, be regarded as a criminal offence."

E.W. Dijkstra

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, but maybe it's not well suited for anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly as someone coming from the Basic camp ZX81, Spectrum 48K, QB, PDS 7.1 recommend that you look at Python. It is very approachable i.e. has a syntax that one quickly can get a hang of, I had Java during my Computer Sciences education and disliked Java because I found it too quirky.

Don't get me wrong I love the idea of OOP however programming needs to be fun, and speaking of easy to learn and fun there is a smashing tutorial series on Python by a guy called Bucky Roberts, referring to himself as thenewboston on youtube - The first lesson can be found on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Mf0h3HphEA well actually he's made more than just one tutorial, he has 3 tutorial series regarding the subject of Python, one is basic Python just called Python Programming Tutorial, one named wxPython Programming Tutorial and the last one named Game Development Tutorial. Oh and Python can be used as OOP as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you learn ANSI C, as there are so many different languages that are based on its syntax.  Much of what you will learn is directly applicable in C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Would a 1994 copy of C for Dummies teach ANSI C?

Comment: In my past experience, some of the Dummy books have been really useful, while some are not so much.  My C class in college used "Programming in ANSI C" by Stephen Kochan.  I found the book to be pretty straight forward and I highly recommend it.

Comment: What is your opinion on C for Dummies Volume 1 by Dan Gookin? Also is this book ANSI C?

Comment: I've never read it, but did I a quick glance on Amazon of its table of contents and it appears to be missing some important topics, one being pointers.  If you have already acquired the book, it will get you off to a good start, but it appears to be very introductory and a bit shallow.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to learn and why. If you are saying youve just learnt about VB.Net then learning OOP concepts would be a good idea, then perhaps Design Patterns such as GoF.

Comment: What is GoF? I've never heard of it?

Comment: Gang Of Four: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: GoF = Gang of Four, a nickname for the 4 authors of the book [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1288902672&sr=8-1) and the book itself.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a subjective question and the answer really depends upon what you want to achieve. Perhaps try exploring another paradigm? Or maybe turn your attention more towards the theory/design side of things and apply the skills you have in learning patterns and architecture?

In such a diverse field as ours with so many good resources for learning available all around, you really are spoilt for choice!